# Does butterknife 7.x work with Kotlin M14?

Tags: android, kotlin, butterknife

I'm trying to use Butterknife with some Kotlin code and also Java code. I know that before M12, there was bad or no support for annotation processing that ButterKnife required. So I have kept my activities in Java. It was working at least in Java with Butterknife 6.x and preM12 Kotlin.
I'm trying now butterknife 7.x with M13 and M14. It should have even annotation processing support, but it's not working for me.  `bind()` function doesn't bind anything in my adapter which is written in Java nor in activity written in Kotlin.

I'm using this in build.gradle (tried latest version on Github):

```
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

dependencies {
   provided files('libs/butterknife-annotations.jar')
   kapt files('libs/butterknife-compiler-8.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar')
   compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.0-SNAPSHOT@aar'
}
```

This doesn't compile. I tried also 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt' which does compile but binding is not working.

I know that there is probably not support in *butterknife* for that yet. But is there any hack to get it working?

Comment: JakeWharton has separately released KotterKnife, isn't that what you need? https://github.com/JakeWharton/kotterknife

Comment: Alternatively, there are the Kotlin Android Extensions. No need for Butterknife.

Comment: Yes, I know about these options. I'm going with anko. But thanks for response.

Comment: also there is a tool **[kapt][1]** that is annotation processing tool for kotlin. Maybe it has solved all problems that were the starting point for developing Kotterknife


  [1]: http://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/05/kapt-annotation-processing-for-kotlin/

Comment: Kotlin Android Extensions is very buggy. Sometimes when I start Android Studio all views provided by `synthetic` marked with red color. Also this does not work correct with fragment. KollerKnife is very straightforward and lightweight solution. Also this PR: https://github.com/JakeWharton/kotterknife/pull/7 implements reset feature, so you can use kotterknife with fragments.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It does work with the current version of Kotlin (1.0.0-beta-3595), I suggest you to take a look at the [android-butterknife](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-examples/tree/master/gradle/android-butterknife) project which can be found inside the JetBrains's [kotlin-examples](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-examples) repo. In short all you need to do is:

1. Add the following to your `app/build.gradle` file:

   ```
   kapt {
       generateStubs = true
   }
   ```
2. Put the following line inside the `dependencies` block of the same `build.gradle` file (assuming you already added `compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'` to your dependencies):

   ```
   kapt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
   ```

And that should be it.

Comment: Also confirmed with stable kotlin 1.0.0.

Comment: As of butterknife 8.x, you now run `kapt` on the compiler lib instead of a second reference to butterknife itself, i.e. `kapt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1'`. JetBrains' example project linked in the answer above has been updated to reflect this change.

Answer (score 3):

Butterknife is supported. Use kapt: [[1]](http://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/05/kapt-annotation-processing-for-kotlin/), [[2]](http://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/06/better-annotation-processing-supporting-stubs-in-kapt/).

Note that Butterknife does not support private Java fields, so you can use the `lateinit` modifier to make it public.

Also, if you use kapt,
`apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'`
line is not needed anymore.

Comment: How to make Butterknife set onClicks and etc with kapt?