# Android: Kotlin with Butterknife

Tags: android, kotlin, butterknife

I'm trying to use Kotlin with Butterknife for my Android Application.

Here is my build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'
    kapt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1'
}

kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}
```

I also has an EditText and I want to show a message using ButterKnife when it is changed:

```
@OnTextChanged(R.id.input)
fun test() {
   toast(1)
}
```

However, nothing happens. I put a breakpoint into the function - and it is not even executed.

P.S: I have heard about kotterknife, however I have seen an [example](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-examples/tree/master/gradle/android-butterknife) with pure Butterknife.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32952049/2949612

Comment: @pRaNaY did you even read the question? I have exactly the same done in my code

Comment: I know it is not a direct answer but with Kotlin, Anko and Kotlin Android Extensions I don't see any use for ButterKnife.

Comment: Did you call `ButterKnife.bind(this)`?

Comment: @JanSlominski unless the OP wants to rewrite the whole application in Kotlin there is still a need to run alongside Java

Comment: better you can use Kotlin extension plugin  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AvMbTY6Vruk

Comment: @JanSlominski Can you explain us why with anko we dont need more buttkernife?

Answer (score 101):

There's no need for butterknife in Kotlin. You can directly use the following:

// app:build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.nikhiljadhav.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.0'
}

kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}
```

// xml layout file

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvHello"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etDemo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp" />
```

// MainActivity.kt file

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        // use the kotlin property
        tvHello.text="Hi bla bla"
        tvId.text="buubububub"
        //set textcolor  
        tvId.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent)) 
        etDemo.hint="nhdodfhfgf"

        tvId.setOnClickListener{ view->
            onClick(view)
        }

        fab.setOnClickListener { view ->
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show()
        }
    }

    fun onClick(view: View) {
        Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show()
    }

    ...
}
```

For onTextChangeListner:

```
etText.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher{
        override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
            TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
            TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
            TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

    })
```

Comment: so how do you use @OnTextChanged with Kotlin Extensions?

Comment: note from a Fragment you need to call from `onViewCreated`
https://antonioleiva.com/kotlin-android-extensions/

Comment: what about string, colors, dimensions bindings?

Comment: This is super great. Looks like you also need to import the xml file such as: `import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*`

Comment: This answer could do with more explanation.

Comment: Just FYI, Google does not recommend using synthetic view references anymore. https://old.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/ala9p2/why_kotlinx_synthetic_is_no_longer_a_recommended/efdvpkg/

Comment: @Michael ```@BindDimen(R.dimen.text_margin) @JvmField var textMargin: Int = 0```

Comment: Kotlin syntethics are deprecated from Nov 2020

Answer (score 53):

In your app level **build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.0'
    kapt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.0'
}
```

**In your Top Level build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.30'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

**Activity**

```
@BindView(R.id.toolbar)  @JvmField var toolbar: Toolbar? = null
```

**or**

```
@BindView(R.id.toolbar) lateinit var toolbar: Toolbar
```

Inside **OnCreate**

```
ButterKnife.bind(this)
```

Comment: Synthetics rule, but sometimes you are not ready to replace them. Thanks for answering the question.

Answer (score 20):

Kotlin creators tell on their site that:
Kotlin Android Extensions plugin (automatically bundled into the Kotlin plugin in Android Studio) solves the same issue: r**eplacing `findViewById` with a concise and straightforward code. Consider using it** unless you're already using ButterKnife and don't want to migrate.

and e.g.

```
// Using R.layout.activity_main from the main source set
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MyActivity : Activity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        textView.setText("Hello, world!")
        // Instead of findViewById(R.id.textView) as TextView
    }
}
```

`textView` is an extension property for `Activity`, and it has the same type as declared in `activity_main.xml`.

Comment: can you post a link to it

Comment: sure. you can find more details here:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html

Answer (score 11):

**In your gradle:**

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.0'
kapt "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.0"
```

**In your activity**

```
@BindView(R.id.toolbar)
lateinit var mToolbar: Toolbar
```

Of course, remember `ButterKnife.bind(this)` and apply the plugin on the top of your app.gradle `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'`

[Check full example](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-examples/tree/master/gradle/android-butterknife)

Full Link: https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-examples/tree/master/gradle/android-butterknife

Answer (score 3):

You need to simply add `ButterKnife.kt` into your source tree from the following link:
https://github.com/JakeWharton/kotterknife
It worked for me.

Comment: Kotter Knife::: Deprecated: This was a terrible idea because it allocates an object for every view reference. Do not use, and do not use anything like it. Use view binding instead.

Answer (score 2):

Add this in your Project Build.gradle

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-4'
ext.butterknife_version = '8.6.0'
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha1'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath "com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:$butterknife_version"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
   }
}
```

And in your app Build.Gradle add this.

```
    //Butterknife
compile "com.jakewharton:butterknife:$butterknife_version"
kapt "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:$butterknife_version"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can implement some extensions to improve your views behavior. Checkout this example for "onTextChange" in a regular editText:

```
fun EditText.onTextChange(callback: (text: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) -> Unit) {
    addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {}

        override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}

        override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
            callback(s, start, before, count)
        }
    })
}
```

Usage:

```
m_editText.onTextChange { text, _, _, _ -> 
   m_textView.text = text
}
```

I vote for kotlin-android-extensions

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin, actually there is no need (or) necessity  for going ButterKnife concepts. because **in your activity you can directly refer the view _id of the layout file** as referred below.

**layout.xml**

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/btn_prestage"
     android:layout_width="20dp"
     android:layout_height="20dp"
     android:background="@drawable/prestaging_off"/>
```

**Activity.kt**

```
 btn_prestage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.staging_on)
 btn_prestage.setOnClickListener{ view ->
            Snackbar.make(view, "My Action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show() }
```

**build.gradle**(app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
   dependencies {... }
}

kapt {
    generateStubs = true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Jake Wharton created new library for kotlin called kotterknife:
https://github.com/JakeWharton/kotterknife
Gradle:

```
compile 'com.jakewharton:kotterknife:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
```

View:

```
val lastName: TextView by bindView(R.id.last_name)

  // Optional binding.
  val details: TextView? by bindOptionalView(R.id.details)

  // List binding.
  val nameViews: List<TextView> by bindViews(R.id.first_name, R.id.last_name)

  // List binding with optional items being omitted.
  val nameViews: List<TextView> by bindOptionalViews(R.id.first_name, R.id.middle_name, R.id.last_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can import all synthetic properties for the free/res/layout/activity_main.xml layout by adding this import:

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
```

Now you can access all views by using there id's no need to initiate findbyid

Comment: "synthetic" is deprecated https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration