# Layout view is not initialized with Butterknife

Tags: kotlin, butterknife

In the following code:

```
class LobbyFragment : Fragment() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var lobbyFragmentHelloService: LobbyFragmentHelloService

    @BindView(R.id.lobby_fragment_hello)
    lateinit var lobbyFragmentHelloTextView: TextView

    lateinit var unbinder: Unbinder

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lobby_fragment, container, false)
        unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view)
        return view
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        sayFragmentHello()
    }

    override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
        AndroidInjection.inject(this)
        super.onAttach(context)
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        unbinder.unbind()
    }

    private fun sayFragmentHello() {
        lobbyFragmentHelloTextView.text = lobbyFragmentHelloService.sayHello()
    }
}
```

lobbyFragmentHelloTextView is never initialized. Butterknife is used to initialize this variable. Why is not initialized by the time sayFramentHello is called?

Comment: You are most likely missing `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'`.

Comment: No. This is clearly a butterknife issue. I removed it. Butterknife is useless in Kotlin.

Comment: What was your ButterKnife version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure what went wrong but to fix the issue, you can consider using kotlin built in synthetic binding and just get rid of butterknife. It's more efficient.

[explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42453010/android-kotlin-with-butterknife#45592221)

Comment: I did then just before you posted your answer and that solved the problem. To be honest, I took that code from a sample app. This just confirms my opinion that developers have become so dependent on ridiculous third party libraries like Butterknife that only end up costing hours to fix problems.